# Editing an ArcGIS Online Hosted Feature Service with ArcGIS Desktop Basic

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, arcgis-online

I'm working to develop a workflow to edit ArcGIS Online hosted feature services on desktop. The `Create Local Copy for Editing` and `Synchronize Local Edits with Server` functionality works as expected for my ArcGIS Desktop Advanced license, but the client only has ArcGIS Desktop Basic.

What's the recommended workflow in this situation? Our current approach is to `Create Local Copy for Editing`, then overwrite the existing feature service on ArcGIS Online. This seems a little heavy handed given how easy it is to edit this data on the web. Are there other options for Desktop editing with a Basic license?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the feature class editable and the user can edit it from an ArcGIS Online WebApp.

Maybe this video will help you: http://video.esri.com/watch/863/feature-service-editing-using-arcgis-desktop

Comment: Very true (and some users will do this), but the user would prefer to use the editing tools available in ArcMap. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Which version of ArcMap is available for the user?

Comment: I did a little bit more research, but other than to `create a local copy` or `edit it online` there are no other options available.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit feature services in ArcGIS Pro with a Basic license!

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/add-a-feature-service-for-editing.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your answer to include some information about how to do what you are suggesting, what it will do, and how it answers the question.  Links can change or disappear without warning, so for this answer to be valuable it needs more information here, using a link as reference rather than as the answer.